# I can't get SMPlayer to work with mpv

Tags: video, smplayer

I have mpv installed and I can run videos with it, but I would like to use mpv with SMPlayer. When I go to **Preferences>General** in SMPlayer, MPlayer/mpv executable points to "/usr/bin/mpv" that leads to an mpv shared library file instead of an executable. I've tried just putting in mpv instead of "/usr/bin/mpv" in SMPlayer. That didn't fix the problem.

`apt-cache policy mpv` output

`mpv:
  Installed: 0.9.2-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 0.9.2-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 0.9.2-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: to enable `mpv` you simply need to change `/usr/bin/mplayer` to `/usr/bin/mpv` then click `apply` it will automatically enable it. If you did so can you start a video? And what distro are you using? Also add the output from the terminal `apt-cache policy mpv`

Comment: The video file doesn't start at all even when I have `/usr/bin/mpv` set in preferences. When I click on a video file it starts SMPlayer as if I just started the program. Nothing else. I'm using 15.10 upgraded from 15.04. In your `/usr/bin` folder is the mpv file type a link to an executable or a shared library?

Comment: I use `mpv` and other available engines with SMplayer all the time. Maybe it's incompatible in some way with 15.10 yet and also you're using the official release in Ubuntu repo and it's older than official `mpv` release which is `0.12`

Comment: though I couldn't find a good mpv ppa for 15.10 maybe it's not there yet. You can check this article meanwhile http://www.webupd8.org/2015/09/smplayer-159-stable-released-with-mpv.html